# Problems with popToRootViewControllerAnimated

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

In my StoryBoard, I have embedded my root view controller inside a Navigation Controller, and this view gets displayed when the app is launched. The user then goes through a series of views, which are basically view controllers presented modally.

I'm trying to implement a function to go back to the root view controller, so I called

```
-(IBAction)backToMenu{
    NSLog(@"Back to menu");
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

but nothing happens. If I do `NSLog(@"%@", self.navigationController");` it prints `null`, so I guess that's the source of my problem. You can't call `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` on a view controller that's been presented modally.

Unless you pass a reference to the root view controller. But is this the right approach? If so, how do you pass a reference to the root view controller? As all my view controllers are instances of a custom subclass of `UIViewController`,  I tried doing inserting this in said class's code :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    [[segue destinationViewController] navigationController] = [[segue sourceViewController] navigationController];    
}
```

but I get an error saying that `navigationController` is not assignable.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation for `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`, it says:

> If you present several view controllers in succession, thus building a
>   stack of presented view controllers, calling this method on a view
>   controller lower in the stack dismisses its immediate child view
>   controller and all view controllers above that child on the stack.

This suggests that you should keep a reference to your root view controller (or otherwise notify it) and call this method on it.  (There's a similar note on the deprecated `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` in case you're using that.)

Answer (score 0):

Does the class that implements the method `-(IBAction)backToMenu` inherit from UIViewController? I get thi skind of error when the class where I'm implementing the popToRootViewControllerAnimated inherits from some other class. To hold a reference to the original navigatorController I would:

1. Declare in the class where backToMenu is implemented, a pointer to a pointer to the navigation controller, something like: `UINavigationController  *navCon;` yo should declare this as a property and then *synthesizeit*.
2. So when you instance the ViewController for this class you can do something like:

`TheClassViewController *theClassVC = [TheClassViewController alloc] initWithNib:@"TheClassViewController" bundle:nil];`

`theClassVC.navCon = self.navigationController;` // Here is where you pass THE reference

`[self.navigationController pushViewController:theClassVC animated:YES];`

Answer (score 0):

Just solved it.

The problem was that, in the StoryBoard, the initial view controller was the root view controller **and not the Navigation Controller** it was embedded in!

Once you set the Navigation Controller as the initial view controller (i.e. drag the arrow so that it points to it), `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` works like a charm.